# how to show boolean data from excel in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I succeed importing data from excel file, but i have a problem when i show it on gridview control:
I have in .xls a column with true or false content and when I show them in gridview it converts this data as chechbox (display:block).

I used an end point to see what happens an it's ok before I display on the gridview.

here is my code:

to import (inside a loop):

```
cmd.CommandText = query;//"Select * from [" + row["TABLE_NAME"] + "];"
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
dt = new DataTable(dtSheetFromExcel.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());                                
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
   ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}
i++;
```

to show data:

```
//Dataset ds
Util.uploadExcelData(fileUpload, path, ref ds, ref errortype);
foreach (DataTable dataTable in ds.Tables)    
{
 GridView gdv = new GridView();                         
 gdv.DataSource = dataTable;
 gdv.DataBind();
 gridExcel.Controls.Add(gdv);
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do exactly, just print the text "true" or "false" instead of making a checkbox?

Comment: yes, i looking for something that change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `gdv.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();`

The binding may need some tweaking, the times I've used it to do this I haven't needed to worry much with binding.

Comment: Sorry, that should be: `dv.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView`

See if that works better.

Comment: thanks, I used this also, but i dind't succeed, I think this problem was when I import the data, vs recognize by default true or false as boolean values instead of string values :S

Comment: Ah, yes, that *would* do it.  I suppose you're already modifying your query to convert it to Strings, but you could also build a fresh DataTable from the contents of the first one and replace the bool values with string True/False.  I realize I'm suggesting the obvious, and I don't *mean* to sound snotty.  :)

Answer (score 0):

that's wire, when i change the contend on .xls file from true to trued or something different the datagridview recognized the entired column as text ... 
it apears to be a reserved word or something ...